# The '_imaging' module for the PIL could not be imported: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django, so I created a simple gallery application which allows me to upload images via Django *admin* app. When I select an image via *ImageField* from my computer and hit *Save*, it gives an error

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/photogallery/photo/add/
The '_imaging' module for the PIL could not be imported: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using Django1.6, apache2.2, Python2.7.5 and PIL is also installed for this version of python.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try uninstalling PIL and installing Pillow. Starting from Django 1.6 Pillow is "the preferred image manipulation library to use with Django" (see [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/)).

Comment: Are you operating in a virtual environment (and is PIL in that virtual environment?)

Comment: Yes I am in virtual environment and installing Pillow solved the problem.

Comment: @qurban Add an answer below and accept,  I used `$ pip install Pillow` and problem solved for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ludwik Trammer suggested, I uninstalled the *PIL* and installed the *Pillow* and the problem solved. *PIL* worked fine for me with the earlier versions of *Django* but not with Django 1.6

Comment: How do I do that? `pip uninstall PIL` `pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 0):

try to install PIL if you are using anaconda distro install this command

```
conda install -c anaconda pillow
```